# Need to know android specific buttons in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to know what the numbered places(in picture) are in Eclipse.

No-1 is a list of API. Is it the target API or API to compile against ?

No-2 is a list of devices, but what is the use of it,I already made an AVD for my 
application. What does it do then?

[image]

Comment: As stated below: "Nexu One" - It says that Your layout below as it looks on Nexus One. The icon was the target Android version from the manifest (take a peek there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current layout you're viewing is rendered based on what it would look like on the Device selected in "No-2". You can try changing it to see how it would scale to different screen sizes and devices. It has no effect on your final application.

"No-1" specifies which android-sdk version it would use to render the view. Thus you would get older looking widgets with a lower api and new holo-styled widgets with newer api levels. Again this does **not** alter anything in your actual application. It just gives you an idea of what your layout will look like in different api levels.

Comment: So does it mean that if I change a device in no-2, I should also change the sdk version(no-1) that the device support(in no-2), to see if expected device works with expected sdk. Am I right?

Comment: Im not sure what you're asking. But if youre talking about the sdk you have set in the Manifest file, that has no relation with these values. Both 1 and 2 simply provide a visual aid to see what your layout would look like in different devices/screen-sizes/api-levels.

Comment: Galaxy nexus runs on android v4.0, now if I set no-2 to Galaxy nexus, shouldn't I also change sdk (no-1) to API 14 bcos Galaxy nexus runs on API 14, If I select a device and then select a SDK that doesnt support that device, will it make sense. BTW I m not talking about manifest sdk version. Thanx

Comment: When you set no-2 to Galaxy Nexus, it doesnt change the rendering to match android v4.0. It only changes the layout according to the Galaxy Nexus' screen resolution. Selecting the api level changes the rendering to match android v4.0 if you set it to 14.

Answer (score 0):

**"Nexu One"** - It says that Your layout below as it looks on Nexus One.

**Android icon** - The sdk version..

Not much

Answer (score 0):

No-1 :-  It show different-different layout . It is very useful at application DESIGNING . 
No-2 : - Which version do you like to run this layout.

There both no-1 and no-2 will be use for DESIGNING APPS and nothing . You can fix your design by include images in drawable , drawable-mdi,.... folders and if required choose layout-large, layout-small, layout-sw360dp (for galaxy 720*1250) etc.

Answer (score 0):

1: is the sdk version for that particular layout

and 2: indicates the device Screen, you can use this to check how your layout will be looked in different screens